# Git ignore xcodeproj file

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I am setting up a team project under `git` source control, and all members of the team will be using different IDE-s. The project is a basic command line application written in `C`. Personally I want to work within Xcode7, but I have a problem with the `xcodeproj` file (or folder) which is also being committed. I dont want this, since other team members dont work with Xcode and this `xcodeproj` file just does a mess when they checkout. I just want to be able to commit my regular source files to `git` and nothing else. What should I do? If the answer is `.gitignore` file, how should it look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add these two lines to `.gitignore`:

```
*.xcodeproj/
DerivedData/
```

The first line excludes the Xcode project directory. The second excludes the default directory created for object files and other build data.

Comment: it still added the xcodeproj.... The file is called "git.gitignore" is that a problem, should it just be ".gitignore"? Also I had to use push.

Comment: No, the file should be named `.gitignore`.